# C++: why boost::ptr_vector resize needs object to have default constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, vector, ptr-vector

I am using a boost::ptr_vector over just std::vector as it will handle the deletion of all of the pointers for me. However when I do:

```
ptr_vector<SoftLabelRandomTreeFunctor> functors;
functors.resize(number_of_functors);
```

It complains that `SoftLabelRandomTreeFunctor` does not have a default constructor. However, I was under the impression that it would just need to resize big enough to fit `number_of_functors` * the size of a pointer to a `SoftLabelRandomTreeFunctor`, not `number_of_functors` * the size of a `SoftLabelRandomTreeFunctor` itself?

Comment: When you increase the size, new pointers are added to the vector *and* initialized with addresses of new objects.

Comment: The point is that is simply makes no sense to resize the container if you don't want to put anything inside. You can just use `reserve` to preallocate the memory if you know you are *going to* insert some elements.

Comment: @KerrekSB The reason I am resizing is because I want to be able to assign to the vector in a random manner, i.e. set poisition 1, and then 0. So functors.replace(1,obj1); functors.replace(0,obj2); so I resize to ensure that I will no go out of bounds

Comment: @Aly: Can't you use `push_back`s instead? Or use a different container, like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, which seems more suitable to what you want to do. The `boost::ptr_vector` is a very specific container for a very specific use case, which doesn't seem to suit yours. Since you explicitly *want* pointers, you should *have* pointers in your visible design.

Comment: @KerrekSB push_back does sequential inserts, i.e. the first call will put the item at position 0, the second will put it at position 1. I want to assign to position 1 first, then position 0 (as you would be able to with an array of fixed size)

Comment: Yes, I know... I've updated the previous comment. The upshot is: use a different container.

Answer (score 3):

I am not really experienced with Boost, so take my answer with a grain of salt. However, skimming through the docs for `boost::ptr_vector` made me think that what you want (as follows from the comments to the question) should be possible to do this way:

```
boost::ptr_vector< boost::nullable<SoftLabelRandomTreeFunctor> > functors;
functors.resize(number_of_functors, 0);
```

The references for you to read and make your own conclusion:

- [Null values](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#null-values)
- [`class nullable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reference.html#class-nullable)
- [`void resize( size_type size, T* to_clone );`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html#modifiers) - see a remark that `to_clone` can be 0 if the container supports nulls

Answer (score 1):

When you write `functors.resize(number_of_functors)` you potentially increase the size of the vector to contain `number_of_functors` elements inside. Since `ptr_vector` by default disallows storing `NULL` values, it needs to put a meaningfull data into the inflated array. The function intends to call `new SoftLabelRandomTreeFunctor()` for every new element and it requires a default constructor for that.

If you want to allow NULLs, you need the `boost::nullable` as suggested by Alexey Kukanov answer, and as in the tutorial included in the manual ([(here)](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/tutorial.html#null-values)).

However, if you just intend to reserve enough memory for `number_of_functors` elements without semantically creating them and without increasing the array size --- you don't need `nullable` and you should call instead:

`functors.reserve(number_of_functors)`

Note that after this, you still need to increase the array size when you put new elements (e.g. via `push_back`). You will have a guarantee though that `push_back` won't call a memory reallocation as long as your size doesn't exceed `number_of_functors`.